# How to integrate with respect to z

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate $2\cos(4z)- 8z\sin(4z)$ with respect to $z$? I integrated the first part normally and the second part I tried to use $uv-vdu$ however I'm still getting the wrong answer.

Comment: What answer are you getting and how?

Comment: I'm getting (1/2)sin(4z) - 2zcos(4z) + (1/2)sin(4z). I did the 2cos(4z) but taking u=4z and du = 4. However, I solved 8zsin(4z) by using uv-vdu. I took u= 8z and dv=sin(4z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, the only tricky part is $\int z\cdot \sin(4z)\,dz$. We can do this with integration by parts ($uv-v\,du$).

Let $u = z$, so $du = dz$, and let $dv = \sin(4z)$, which makes $v = \frac{-1}{4}\cos(4z)$.

Then 
$$\int z\cdot \sin(4z)\,dz = 
\int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du = 
\frac{-1}{4}\cdot z \cdot \cos(4z) + \int\frac{-1}{4}\cos(4z)\,dz =\\ 
\frac{-1}{4}\cdot z\cdot \cos(4z) + \frac{-1}{16}\sin(4z)$$

Multiply that by 8 and add it to the rest of your answer and you should be good!

Comment: LaTeX advice: instead of `$\int z*sin(4z)dz$` try `$\int z\cdot\sin(4z)\,dz$`, or just `$\int z \sin(4z)\,dz$`. Instead of `$\frac{-1}{4}$`, try `$-\frac{1}{4}$`.

Also, for longer equations, use `$$...$$` rather than `$...$`

Comment: All helpful! I like leaving the negative sign within the fraction, simply because that's how I write it. It lumps the negative and the constant together, which is how I think about it.

Comment: I've gone ahead and made a few changes myself; of course, I left your fractions as you like them.  Feel free to change it back (see the "rollback" option next to your edit [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/762323/revisions)), but I hope you like it better this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a sign problem, or have left out a sine term; as you point out first part is easy;

$\int 2 \cos (4z) dz = 1/2 \sin(4z)$

ignoring the constant of integration for now. Then, for the second part, we'll ignore the minus for now and work out $\int 8z\sin(4z) dz$. If you use integration by parts, you could choose

$u = 8z$

$du = 8$

$dv = \sin(4z)$

$v = -(1/4)\cos(4z)$

Then $\int u dv =  uv - \int v du$ becomes

$-2z\cos(4z) + 2\int \cos(4z) = -2z\cos(4z) + (1/2) \sin(4z) $

Finally, combining all parts and taking account of the minus and the constant of integration you get

$1/2 \sin(4z) + 2z\cos(4z) - (1/2) \sin(4z) = 2z\cos(4z) + C $

I think you were right initially, you just left out the minus sign so the two sine terms didn't cancel, or forgot to include one of the terms.